# preferable return type: void or bool

Tags: java, c++, return-type

Many times, I run in a situation where I have a option to either return a bool or void. For example consider the case:

```
public (return_type) updateQueryStats(String ident, Double execTime) {
    Double newAvgTime;    
    //calculate average query time.
    avgTime.put(ident, newAvgTime);
    //return true;
}
```

Let us say that these are to be used as API or library by other users. Although both are functionally same, which one is a better practice.

Comment: In what condition would you return a `false` value?

Comment: @RohitJain in this case, at no condition. I just wanted to be aware of conventions, that's all.

Comment: Then I wouldn't have the return type as `boolean`. For denoting a failure, you can rather throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method will always return `true`, and in no case a `false` value. Or you are just putting `boolean` return type to denote successful database query, I would avoid using `boolean` return type. You should better keep the return type as `void`, as technically the method wouldn't return anything. And in case of failure, you can throw an exception - Unchecked, or checked, that you can decide, based on whether you want to proceed on failure or not.

Answer (score 2):

For update queries returning `Boolean` make the user aware of success/failure of the operation.

Comment: Maybe in C++ - in Java it would be more idiomatic to throw an exception on error.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Since when? Perhaps you are talking about `HashSet#add()`?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: No, HashMap.put returns the previous value that was present for that key, if any. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V)

Comment: @RohitJain, Sorry! messed up!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran No issues. Happens often :)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to return Boolean you can throw an exception when update operation failed

Answer (score 0):

Returning a `boolean` could be used when you want a way to check if the operation made in the method was successful or not.

In the other hand, if you want your method to don't return anything (`void`), you could use `try-catch` clauses to handle problems.

Of course it depends on how your program is working, you must choose the way that fits better to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no hard-and-fast rule here, let me layout my personal guidelines:

- If the net effect of the operation[1] did not take place, report the failure via an exception. This will force the caller to be aware of the failure. A return value can be silently ignored.
- If there are two (or more) different situations[2] in which the same expected net effect can be achieved, use a `boolean` (or a more elaborate return type, e.g., `enum`) to report which of the situations was encountered.
- Otherwise, void `void`.

[1] here: `avgTime.get(ident) == execTime`

[2] For instance, `avgTime` might already have a value associated with `ident`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely go for `void`. You can change it later if you find out that you need some return value. Such a change is much simpler than the other way round.

You may also find out that you need to return something else (e.g. `newAvgTime`) instead of your `boolean`.

Moreover, how would you document the return value?

- **Return true on success?**: What is a "success"? You should throw if something goes really wrong.
- **Always return true.?**: What is this good for?

Note that returning a value means you have to obtain it somehow, and this may cost performance